# C# How do you build up a collection in the IServiceCollection across library boundaries?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, service-provider, servicecollection

I inject a generic list `List<ICommand>` through a constructor. Users of my library should be able to add their own implementations of `ICommand`.  All of the `ICommand` implementations are known at compile time.  Currently, I add to the `ServiceCollection` something like the following (i realize there are other ways to do this as well) :

```
ServiceCollection.AddSingleton<List<ICommand>>>(new List<ICommand>()
{
   new Command1(),
   new Command2(),
   new etc....
});
```

This works well for adding `ICommand` implementations defined in the current library.  However, I want others to use my library and add their own implementations of `ICommand`.  How do they add their own `ICommand` to this `List<ICommand>` from outside of this library?

I am using this specific example with `List<T>` to understand a more general problem: "how do you build up an object ***ACROSS*** library boundaries using `ServiceCollection`"?

Comment: By exposing your `ICommand` and registering them one by one (both you and your consumers), not as a list as a singleton, and requesting an `IEnumerable<ICommand>` where you need all registered commands.

Comment: @CodeCaster that works. I never found that in the documentation. Thanks. If you writeup an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: Nah I'm sure there are duplicates that explain it, couldn't find any that quickly. Feel free to self-answer with your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register the same type more than once with the `IServiceCollection` and the `ServiceProvider` will ***automatically*** resolve all of them to an `IEnumerable<>`.

For instance, if you want users of your library to add custom `ICommand` objects they would simply do the following in their own library:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICommand, CustomCommand1>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICommand, CustomCommand2>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICommand, CustomCommand3>();
```

The `ServiceProvider` will automatically add them to the list of `IEnumerable<ICommand>` where requested (across library boundaries).